# How to set a users' password in Collabnet SubVersion Edge

Tags: svn, repository, collabnet, subversion-edge

I know this may be a silly question, but I'm not able to find an answer.
I'm setting up repositories access rules in Collabnet Subversion Edge (running under Linux) according to this link: https://svn.help.collab.net/entries/24785311-Define-repository-access-rules. As the documentation mentions, I'm definining groups and users belonging to such groups, as well as granting r/rw permissions.

However, I don't understand where I'm supposed to set the password for each user added to the rules configuration. I understand that users that have access to Collabnet console are not the same as users that have access to source code control operations. So...how can I create a "source control user"? Where am I supposed to set his/her password?

I'm not using LDAP, I just want users to type their passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like the user has to be created on the Collabnet admin console without any roles associated to him/her. That's the place to set the password and additional details for user. I've tried it and it works that way.